# what to use for automatic signout of an App after 30 min in android

Tags: java, android

I want my application to Automatically signout after 30 minutes.so i am confused with lots of option i have.
1.handlers 
but i think if i use handler it won't calculate the display sleep time and i can also not able to resume the handler in another activity.
2.AlarmManager 
I dont know much about it but i think it use more cpu memory.
3.CountDownManager like how i used below

```
new CountDownTimer(40000, 1000) { //40000 milli seconds is total time, 1000 milli seconds is time interval

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
  }
  public void onFinish() {
 }
}.start();
```

but can i resume CountDownManager process in another activity
4.timer in java 
it will create another thread

or is that nessesary that i should use service and include one of the above methods.because there are possibility that user can press home button and the app goes to onPause() state.or the display can sleep after some time.i also dont want my app to slow down .will using service will slow down my app.can anyone help me.

Comment: `AlarmManager I dont know much about it but i think it use more cpu memory.` why? I don't think sooo. this would be better option..

Comment: TimerTask is good option in your case.

Comment: if i use AlarmManager what happens if my activity goes to onpause or if i pressed home button from my app.will the alarm manager throw alert after 30 min

Answer (score 4):

You can use a timeout, here is a simple example.

```
    public static final int TIMEOUT_FOR_APPLICATION = 1800000;//exit app after 30 minutes



    private void timeout() {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

        finish();//or whatever you want to do


        }
    }, TIMEOUT_FOR_APPLICATION);

}
```

Hope this is what are you looking for...

Cheers

Comment: what happens if user goes to another activity.should i create new handler

Comment: or what happens if screens display goes off

Comment: i dont want the app to signout after 30 minutes of user login.i just want to signout if user stays more than 30 minutes for idle without touching the screen

Answer (score 2):

use **AlaramManager** and set  alarm after 30 minute. and you have to use pending intent for that so your service will be called after 30 minute. and you can do code there.

You can see [How to set alarm programetically?](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/30/how-to-use-alarm-service-in-android/)

and if you wants to get idle time than if your gets touch or focus than you can reset that alarm.

and for screen off you can write code at onPause and onResume.

Comment: At  first i used handler but .my App get force closed frequently.because  i have to call and remove handler for every event since we cant reset handler timer.Finally i used timer my problem solved.

Comment: tks sanket.i have one more doubt.it is very nasty to cancel alaram manager for every click events(editText click,parent linearlayout click,all button clicks).is there any way to detect when user just touches the screen .i tried using touch event ,gestures etc but it doesn't support when i click buttons and editText.

Comment: sorry, i have not tried that.will let you know if i get any answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add a field lastLogin in your class User.

```
private static final Long EXPIRE_TIME = 1000L * 60 * 30; //30M
private static final Long DELAY_TIME = 1000L * 60 * 5;
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new ContainerCleaner(), EXPIRE_TIME, DELAY_TIME, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

public class ContainerCleaner implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        UserCache.cleanupContainer();
    }
}
```

in UserCache

```
public synchronized void cleanupContainer() {
    Collection<User> users= userCache.values();
    for (Userp : users) {
        if (isExpired(p)) {
            expire(p);
        }
    }
}
private boolean isExpired(SessionProfile sessionProfile) {
    if (sessionProfile == null) {
        return false;
    }
    Long lastAccess = sessionProfile.getValue(Name.LASTACCESS);
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - lastAccess > EXPIRE_TIME;
}
```

The code is from my webservice. It will detect if user isExpired every 5 mins.

Comment: i dont want the app to signout after 30 minutes of user login.i just want to signout if user stays more than 30 minutes for idle without touching the screen